# Sharing ARKit experiences over the web

Tags: ios, arkit

We're looking to share AR experiences (ARWorldMap) over the web (not necessarily to devices nearby, I'm referring to data that can be stored to some server and then retrieved by another user).

Right now we're looking into [ARWorldMap](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldmap) which is pretty awesome, but I think it only works on the same device AND with devices nearby. We want to be able to delete these constraints (and therefore save the experience over the web on some server) so that everyone else can automatically see 3D things with their devices (not necessarily at the same time) exactly where they were places.

Do you know if it's possible to send the archived data (ARWorldMap) to some server in some kind of format so that another user can later retrieve that data and load the AR experience on their device?

Comment: Are you looking for something like Google Cloud Anchors ?

Comment: @AxelGuilmin Yeah, maybe! Does that work even if the devices are no longer nearby? For example, device A places something and then device B sees the same environment some time later (when device A is no longer around). I see there's a 24h limitation.

Answer (score 2):

The `ARWorldMap` contains the feature points in the enviroment around the user. For example, the exact position and size of a table but including all the other points found by the camera. You can visualize those with the [`debugOptions`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scndebugoptions/2882038-showfeaturepoints). 
It does not make sense to share those to a user that is not in the same room.

What you want to do is share the interactions between the users, eg when an object was placed or rotated. 
This is something you would need to implement yourself anyway since `ARWorldMap` only contains anchors and features.

I can recommend [Inside Swift Shot](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc2018/videos/play/wwdc2018/605/) from last years WWDC as a starting point.

Comment: I’m looking for something that lets people place 3D objects around a city and have people see them exactly where they were placed, even with years apart. It sounds like what you’re proposing is something that can be shared at the same time, I’m looking for something more asynchronous if that makes any sense.

Comment: The `ARWorldMap` won't help you with that. You'd need a database where you store the GPS coordinates and the orientation. To get the same orientation on all devices use the [`.gravityAndWorldMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessionconfiguration/worldalignment/gravityandheading) world alignment. Maybe ask a new, more precise question if there are more problems

Answer (score 1):

Yep technically it’s possible as according to docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldmap/archiving_world_map_data_for_persistence_or_sharing). You will have to use the nsssecure coding protocol, might have to extend if you aren’t using a swift backend though. It’s still possible as the arkit anchors are defined by a mix of point maps, rotational data , and image algos. Just implement portions of codable to JSON and  voila it’s viable for most backends. Of course this is easier said then done.

Comment: Thanks! So you’re saying it’s entirely possible for people to scan the environment, save all the data to a server and then have another user download and load that data, even with years apart?

Comment: Years apart would be difficult, ARKIT uses visual inertial odometry in order to correctly calibrate. With this in mind, the curvature of the earth makes it a bit more difficult to ensure locations stay in the same spot over years at a time. It is definitely possible algorithmically as FB was playing around with the same concept recently. Thinking off the top of my head you could probably export the data with things like CLocation. Try to align the world map coordinate system with the client, finally using some loss function minimize the error. Not great, but let me think for a bit.